# problem with savon gem and special characters

Tags: ruby, xml, savon

I'm implementing a ruby interface to soap services connecting to a special database called yardi. In order to do that, I use the savon gem.

Many of the required services have already been implemented. However, some services in yardi require as a parameter a full XML compliant with a given yardi provided xds. I'm having problems with these services.

The problem fundamentally is that savon changes the received xml and changes some characters; for example `<`, `>`, `"`, etc.

This is an real example of xml passed to a service:

```
<YsiTran xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns=""><Charges><Charge><Amount>100.0</Amount><AccountId>49610000</AccountId><ChargeCodeId>rentr</ChargeCodeId><Date>2017-01-23T00:00:00</Date><Notes>Charge with segments</Notes><PersonId>t0001306</PersonId><PostMonth>2017-04-01</PostMonth><PropertyId>385pa</PropertyId><Reference>Internet</Reference><UnitId>B3</UnitId><Segment1>collect</Segment1><Segment2>Technical</Segment2><Segment3>After due date</Segment3><Segment4>NA</Segment4><Segment5>IT</Segment5><Segment6>Owner</Segment6><Segment7>Testing</Segment7><Segment8>Testing</Segment8><Segment9>Employee</Segment9><Segment10>Sigma</Segment10><Segment11>January</Segment11><Segment12>Block 1</Segment12></Charge></Charges></YsiTran>
```

I'm pretty sure this xml is correct because I have tested it by using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org). That is, when I put the xml to SoapUI with the given xml the service responds correctly.

Now, when I put the previous xml to savon and I see the request, I notice that the xml is transformed to

```
&lt;YsiTran xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot; xmlns=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;Charges&gt;&lt;Charge&gt;&lt;Amount&gt;100.0&lt;/Amount&gt;&lt;AccountId&gt;49610000&lt;/AccountId&gt;&lt;ChargeCodeId&gt;rentr&lt;/ChargeCodeId&gt;&lt;Date&gt;2017-01-23T00:00:00&lt;/Date&gt;&lt;Notes&gt;Charge with segments&lt;/Notes&gt;&lt;PersonId&gt;t0001306&lt;/PersonId&gt;&lt;PostMonth&gt;2017-04-01&lt;/PostMonth&gt;&lt;PropertyId&gt;385pa&lt;/PropertyId&gt;&lt;Reference&gt;Internet&lt;/Reference&gt;&lt;UnitId&gt;B3&lt;/UnitId&gt;&lt;Segment1&gt;collect&lt;/Segment1&gt;&lt;Segment2&gt;Technical&lt;/Segment2&gt;&lt;Segment3&gt;After due date&lt;/Segment3&gt;&lt;Segment4&gt;NA&lt;/Segment4&gt;&lt;Segment5&gt;IT&lt;/Segment5&gt;&lt;Segment6&gt;Owner&lt;/Segment6&gt;&lt;Segment7&gt;Testing&lt;/Segment7&gt;&lt;Segment8&gt;Testing&lt;/Segment8&gt;&lt;Segment9&gt;Employee&lt;/Segment9&gt;&lt;Segment10&gt;Sigma&lt;/Segment10&gt;&lt;Segment11&gt;January&lt;/Segment11&gt;&lt;Segment12&gt;Block 1&lt;/Segment12&gt;&lt;/Charge&gt;&lt;/Charges&gt;&lt;/YsiTran&gt;
```

As someone could notice, for a reason that I ignore savon changed some symbols.

I'm performing the request some like this:

```
client.call(service_name.intern, 
            message: { # other parameters
                       'TransactionXml' => transaction_xml })
```

`client` is a savon object and `transaction_xml` is a ruby string containing the xml.

Any clue, tip? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a XML message and can't get it to work with Savon's ruby objects then you can send verbatim XML like this:

```
client.call(service_name.intern, xml: "<tag1>values</tag1>")
```

The details are described in the documentation http://savonrb.com/version2/locals.html

Comment: ok. Thank you; I'll test it. However, I wonder how should be done for services receiving the xml along with other parameters?

Comment: build the client with :namespace, :namespaces, log: true, log_level: :debug, pretty_print_xml: true and look what the result is. Savon uses Builder for the XML body. Sometimes I found it too complicated to use it to build my message. I build the XML from a string instead. If it works, is maintainable and performant then I move on to the next problem :-).

Comment: Hi Steffen. I solved the problem by building the request through `build` method, then I put `client.call(name.intern, xml: req.gsub("\&lt;", "<").gsub("\&gt;", ">")'. That is, I replace the ill symbols. Not exactly a good way but that works.  Thank you